# isnumeric VBA what am i doing wrong here with this function?

Tags: vba, function, range

```
Dim RX as range

Set RX=Application.InputBox(prompt:=" Enter the range for X", Type:=8)

if not isnumeric(RX) then
    msgbox(" Please use only numbers")
    exit sub
end if
```

The problem is that Excel executes the command regardless there are character or not
so my problem is that I want it to check the range and if there are any character to show the msgbox. If there are not any characters continue.

Comment: Executes *which* command?

Comment: Always shows "Please use only numbers" even if there are only numbers in the range RX

Comment: `isnumeric` is not for "characters," it is for testing for convertability to a number. `IsNumeric(array)` will return `False`. `RX.Value` will return an array if there are multiple cells in `RX`. `IsNumeric(Empty)` will return `True`.

Comment: ok but how can i check if my range contain any character?

Comment: Have you tried `IsNumeric(RX.Value)`?

Comment: yeap same error again. All i want is to check the RX for any non-numerical but everytime i try something i always show " Please use only numbers"

Comment: can you give sample data of what is correct in the field, because a range makes no sense - spaces or commas will always trigger it

Comment: oh its clear now that your not typing the vaues in the input box but actually a range of cells, - Use data validation on the cells to ensure numbers!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this should work:

```
Sub test()
Dim RX As Range

Set RX = Application.InputBox(prompt:=" Enter the range for X", Type:=8)
If WorksheetFunction.Count(RX) <> Application.CountA(RX) Then
    MsgBox (" Please use only numbers")
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

`COUNTA` and `COUNT` are worksheet functions that you can use in VBA. `COUNTA` returns the number of non-blank cells. `COUNT` returns the number of cells with numbers. In other words `COUNTA` counts any content, while `COUNT` only counts numbers. If they're different, then some of the cells with content don't have numbers.

Also, this code ignores blank cells and counts things like "4" as text.

Comment: You're welcome. Please see my updated answer for an explanation.